# iOS: Identify User turned off Push Notification from APNS provider

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I am trying to find if user turned off push notification from APNS provider.

Here is the scenario

1. User register for APNS and registers the token with Provider.
2. User turns off notification from the settings.
3. The app is currently not running..

If provider tries to send any push notification to the device will it fail? 
or if I query the feedback service will it report it?

From my testing so far, the APNS returns success even after user turned off push notification and feedback service does NOT report the token.

Whereas if User uninstall the app I can see the device token on Feedback service.

Answer (score 1):

The push notification workflow has been tedious with no request/response model. Every time you send a push notification, you must then poll the APNS Feedback service to check each device token is still accepting your pushes.

Based on WWDC video, since iOS 9, we will get feedback if push receiver turned off push notification when we send push notification.

[Check this link](http://odecee.com.au/wwdc-2015-big-changes-to-apple-push-notifications/)

The APNS Feedback server will take time to update push token status. It looks like not a dynamic synchronise service, currently.

Comment: The new provider API does instant feedback on App Uninstall, but will that notify even when user turns off notification... because current provider API doesn't do that...

Comment: @Mohan Maybe we should think about use a server to keep user usage status, like what Flurry and Google Analytics do.